# bash shell history mechanism not reliable?

Tags: bash, command-history

My typical work flow at the bash prompt consists in typing commands and retrieving them using the <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> "literal" mechanism.

I have noticed over possibly the last couple of years that there are times where a command randomly disappears from the bash history.

Say I type and execute successfully the following:

```
$ command A arg1 arg2
$ command B arg3
$ command C arg4
```

… and type <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> `arg1` — e.g. I get a "failed-reverse-i-search `arg1' ..." error.

Something of interest is that if I follow up with a:

```
$ history | less
```

... `command A` is indeed NOT the history... but I have a line that starts with an asterisk in "column 0" of the history ­— column 0 means the column just left of the column where the commands logged in the history start ­— followed by a blank line.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

This is on a debian/linux stable (buster) running bash 5.0.3.

Comment: IIRC it happens when the line in history is edited, but I can't remember what settings control that etc

Answer (score 3):

> Has anyone seen anything like this?

Yes. To reproduce:

1. Run `echo foo`.
2. Run `echo bar`.
3. <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> so `echo foo` appears (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>`foo`, so `echo foo` appears, then hold <kbd>→</kbd> to get to the end of the line).
4. Hold <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, turn `echo foo` into an empty line, do not execute.
5. <kbd>↓</kbd>, so `echo bar` appears.
6. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute `echo bar` again.

Then `history` will print an empty entry where you might expect `echo foo`. It will be marked with `*` meaning *this entry has been edited*.

Check the `revert-all-at-newline` readline variable (see `man 3 readline`).

- Temporary setting: run `bind 'set revert-all-at-newline On'` in Bash.
- Persistent setting for new Bash instances: place `set revert-all-at-newline On` in `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: Excellent. Used your scenario to re-create. Since I don't use cursor arrows or Backspace preferring CTRL+U CTRL+W CTRL+A CTRL+E etc… it's not obvious how I manage to run into this ­— on rare occasions… must be a scenario where perhaps I mistype my search argument and clear the command-line before I retry a CTRL+R…? But now I know about this readline feature I'll just set revert-all-at-newline variable to On (bind -V shows it's currently off in my profile) to be on the 'safe side'… and this should take care of the problem. Must count myself as very lucky indeed I got an informed answer so fast!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space before your command, it will not be logged.

Comment: No. In this particular case the command is a compilation which was retrieved a few dozen times during the session, with the appearance on the screen of the command followed by a CTRL+A to get out of command-retrieval mode and move the cursor to the beginning of the command and then followed by <Enter>.

Comment: Just tested in my setup. If I enter <space+command> (something I do not use frequently) the command is not logged in the history list (as expected) but I do not get an empty line in the history (with an asterisk in the column between the command number and the commands proper) either: if I do command A + command B (prefixed by a space) + command C there is not trace in the history list of my having entered anything in between command A and command C.  Seems like a description of what exactly these empty lines with an asterisk are might help?